# Convert com.google.protobuf.ByteString to String

Tags: java

I have a Bytestring that I need to display to the console in java.

The Bytestring is of type com.google.protobuf.ByteString,

I am using:

```
System.out.println(myByteString);
```

however, when it is printed out in the terminal it is in this form:

```
\n\325\a\nk\b\003\032\v\b\312\371\336\343\005\020\254\200\307S\
```

How can I display the string in ASCII characters instead of this encoding?

I have tried using `System.out.println(myByteString.toString());`

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this was ASCII data to begin with?

Comment: I'm not sure what the data was to begin with

Comment: If it does not print nicely with  @Luk's answer, it is probably not textual data.

Comment: Is there anyway to find out what encoding it is?

Comment: That should be specified by whoever gave you that Protobuf. Doesn't it come with documentation? But *everyone* these days uses UTF-8, so if it is not that ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(myByteString.toString("UTF-8"));
```

or whatever encoding you are using.

Check out this link:
[Google Developers: Class ByteString](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString#toString-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure that you will be using UTF-8 then you can simply use

```
myByteString.toStringUtf8()
```

or

If you are not sure about the charset refer this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html?is-external=true) and use something similar to Luk's answer

```
myByteString.toString("US-ASCII")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need call:

```
Base64.encodeToString(myByteString.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)
```